# Php/html/mysql User updating not working

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having a problem. I'm working on a custom cms for my site and for some reason the users will not update in the admin panel. It pulls there ID and displays there information in the proper fields, but it will not update and I have no clue why. It just refreshes with the same info, doesn't update my the database or anything. I've tried to fix this, but it won't work. I did different alterations, but all were fails so I decided to just post the original one with a few bug fixes not relating to the updating process.

Heres the whole code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = '".$id."'");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $username1 = $_POST['Username'];
  $email1 = $_POST['Email'];
  $password1 = $_POST['Password'];
  $f_name = $_POST['FName'];
  $l_name = $_POST['LName'];
  $rank1 = $_POST['Rank'];
  $skype1 = $_POST['SkypeID'];

  $db->query("UPDATE users SET (Email, Username, FName, LName, Rank, SkypeID) VALUES(''.$email1.'', ''.$username1.'', ''.$f_name.'', ''.$l_name.'', ''.$rank1.'', ''.$skype1.'') WHERE Id = ".$id."");
}

?>
<b>Update User</b>


<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $username = $row['Username'];
  $email = $row['Email'];
  $fname = $row['FName'];
  $lname = $row['LName'];
  $rank = $row['Rank'];
  $skype = $row['SkypeID'];
}
?>
<form method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo($username); ?>"><br>
  Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo($email);?>"><br>
  Passowrd: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
  First Name: <input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php echo($fname);?>"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="l_name" value="<?php echo($lname); ?>"><br>
  Rank: <input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo($rank); ?>"><br>
  Skype: <input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo($skype); ?>">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Update User</button>
</form>
```

Config file/$db:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

function registerSession($name, $value)
{
    $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I have fixed the problem, I changed the query to this

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET Email= '$email1' , Username= '$username1' , FName= '$f_name' , LName= '$l_name', Rank= '$rank1' , SkypeID= '$skype1' WHERE Id = ".$id."") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: are you updating table on submit button? calling same php again?

Comment: I'm updating already existing tables

Comment: echo $id on 1st line see if you are geting id

Comment: If that is the whole code, where are you defining $db?

Comment: I'm getting the ID, its pulling the id and all that users info, its just when I change and the info and hit the update button, it doesn't update

Comment: @Anigel you are right missed that he is not including any file also.

Comment: Sorry, I am including files, I just didn't show it

Comment: I'm including a config file

Comment: take id in hidden field and POST that also.

Comment: @Abhishekkadadi What?

Comment: Try checking for errors after your update. I can't say for sure what code or syntax to use as I do not know what $db is but for a guess try echoing out $db->error

Comment: ID: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo($id); ?> grab it $_POST['id']; and pass it to table

Comment: @Anigel They're no errors after I hit update, just that it doesn't update. It just refreshes

Comment: You should thank god that it is at least showing old values. There are so many problems.. You are using POST but using $_GET to get id then your names in form is all lowercase but you are getting using Title case in PHP...

Comment: @atul Hmm please explain?

Comment: @user3051246 it will show no errors as you are not checking for any, you are just running a query and hoping it works, all DB libraries either offer a method to check for errors or a return value to show a query worked, you are not looking for errors so not seeing any. The fact it is not updating and just leaving the old values there, shows the query is failing, you just need to ask it why it is failing.

Comment: I explained two problems in my previous comment

Comment: @Anigel Sorry i'm new to php so

Comment: None of you can give me a straight up answer? I'm still learning so I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You still haven't told us what $db is. We cant tell you how to fix code we cannot see

Comment: $db is in my config file, pretty much the statement that connects me to my database

Comment: Just some suggestions: 

Remove single quotes in  `VALUES(''.$email1.'', ''.$username1.'', ''.$f_name.'', ''.$l_name.'', ''.$rank1.'', ''.$skype1.'') WHERE Id = ".$id."");` such that it becomes `VALUES($email1, $username1, $f_name, $l_name, $rank1, $skype1) WHERE Id = ".$id."");`. And add `ini_set('display_errors',1);` to the top of the PHP code to make sure errors are displayed(if you are running your script locally)

Comment: @deepal Thanks, no errors are being displayed though

Answer (score 0):

I cringed when I saw this...

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
```

Because you have yet to tell us what `$db` is, based on the looks of things I'm going to guess its a `mysql_*` function? I would enjoy watching someone SQL injecting this! Show us how `$db` is created (It better be at least `mysqli`, if not `PDO`! If not, Google "mysqli" or "PDO") please?

It's hard to tell what your problem is.

Comment: Its a mysqli function

Comment: Could you show us your config file so we can better understand what `$db` is?

Comment: I updated the post so you see the config file, its nothing, but a msqli function to connect to the database